# No more disk space on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using a D class EC2 which is supposed to be a storage optimized EC2. I have about 20 GB of files that I need to write to disk. I am getting an out of disk space  error once the total size of files reaches 15 GB. The instance is supposed to have way more than this. Why am I getting this error? How can I write more than 15GB of data to a D class EC2?

Answer (score 1):

From [Amazon EC2 Instance Types - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/):

> D2 instances feature up to 48 TB of HDD-based local storage, deliver high disk throughput, and offer the lowest price per disk throughput performance on Amazon EC2.

Please note that this is **local storage**, which is very fast but the contents of these disks is lost if the instance is stopped. Therefore, it is recommended for **temporary storage** only.

**Linux**

I launched a `d2.xlarge` Linux instance.

I then followed instructions from [How to use “Instance Store Volumes” storage in Amazon EC2?](https://serverfault.com/a/433796/267968):

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/xvda: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 70E4A118-98BD-4BF4-8DF9-6926A964902A

Device       Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/xvda1    4096 16777182 16773087   8G Linux filesystem
/dev/xvda128  2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/xvdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000387309568 bytes, 3907006464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/xvdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000387309568 bytes, 3907006464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/xvdd: 1.8 TiB, 2000387309568 bytes, 3907006464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

This showed 3 disks, each of 1.8TiB.

I then formatted and mounted them:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdc
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdd
sudo mkdir /mnt/disk1
sudo mkdir /mnt/disk2
sudo mkdir /mnt/disk3
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdb /mnt/disk1
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdc /mnt/disk2
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdd /mnt/disk3
```

I then viewed the mounted disks:

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         15G     0   15G   0% /dev
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            15G  436K   15G   1% /run
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  1.3G  6.8G  16% /
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdb       1.8T   77M  1.7T   1% /mnt/disk1
/dev/xvdc       1.8T   77M  1.7T   1% /mnt/disk2
/dev/xvdd       1.8T   77M  1.7T   1% /mnt/disk3
```

I was then able to use the disks. (Tip: Change permissions on the mount folders so you don't need to `sudo` all the time.)

**Windows**

I also booted up a `d2.xlarge` Windows instance. I then had to:

- Run **Disk Management**
- Bring each of the 3 disks online
- Initialized the disks
- Created a new Simple Volume for each disk
- They appeared as `D:`, `E:` and `G:`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there are multiple user profiles, in case if there are you may not have permissions to see them and this will not allow you to see the space occupied by them.